Suppose $H$ is normal in $G$. $H$ and the factor group $G/H$ are both cyclic and $\gcd(|H|, |G/H|)=1$. Prove or disprove that $G$ is cyclic.

Suppose $H$ is normal in $G$. $H$ and the factor group $G/H$ are both cyclic and $\gcd(|H|, |G/H|)=1$. Prove or disprove that $G$ is cyclic.

I wonder if this statement is true or not, and I don't know how to prove that or give a counterexample.
Suppose $H =\langle h\rangle$, $|H|=m$, and $G/H= \langle gH\rangle$, $|G/H|=n$.
I think we should imply $gh$ has order $mn$ in some way, but I can only say (1) $o(gh)\mid mn$ and (2) $o(gh)\mid n$ by:
(1) Lagrange Theorem and
(2) $(gh)^k = g^kh^s$, for some $s\in\mathbb{Z}$ (We cannot say $(gh)^k = g^kh^k$ since $G$ is not necessary abelian, right...? ) by induction:
If $k= 0$, $(gh)^0 = g^0h^0 = e$ and if $k= 1$, $(gh)^1 = g^1h^1$
Suppose it holds for $k= 1\Rightarrow (gh)^{(l+1)} = g^lh^s(gh)= (g^l)(h^sg)h = g^lgh^qh = g^{(l + 1)}h^{(q + 1)}\Rightarrow$ It holds for all $k\in N$
For negative integers, use $-k$, then it holds for all $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.
Then suppose $o(gh)= k$,  $(gh)^k= e = g^kh^s= g^{mn}h^m$, $$g^{k-mn} = h^{m-s},$$
which implies $g^{k-mn} = h^{m-s}\in H\cap
\langle g\rangle$, then $g^{k-mn} = h^{m-s} = e$ since $H$ and $\langle g\rangle$ have relatively prime orders.
So, $n\mid k-mn\Rightarrow n\mid k$.
**Now, it only suffices to prove that $m|k$ --$(\star)$, then $k\mid\mathrm{lcm}(m,n)$. **
Combining (1), (2), and $(\star)$, we get $k= mn$, then $gh$ has order $mn$ $\Rightarrow$ $\langle gh\rangle= G\Rightarrow G$ is cyclic.
I want to know how to show $(\star)$ or a counterexample of this statement or some mistakes in my proving process.
I am not good at typing code, so some symbols look weird, sorry..Moreover, I'm a beginner at Algebra, so I always need detailed proof. Thanks.

Are you familiar with $S_3$?

Yes, the permutation group?

-1 For lack of effort as there are simple small counterexamples. In fact the smallest group $G$ with a nontrivial subgroup $H$ such that $\gcd(|H|,|G/H|)=1$ is a counterexample.

@Korean man have you ever heard of a beginner?

Your doordash order is up.

@Servaes there are two "smallest" groups that satisfy those conditions and only one is a counterexample.

Thanks for correcting my mistake. I really need to work on improving my coding skills.

For a counterexample,  consider the group:   $$G=\Bbb Z_3\rtimes\Bbb Z_2.$$
It's not cyclic because it's not abelian. It has a normal subgroup $\Bbb Z_3,$ and $G/\Bbb Z_3\cong \Bbb Z_2.$
$G=S_3.$

Why, oh why, would you (under)describe it as a semidirect product and not as $S_3$? (The direct product is also a semidirect product). (No, I didn't downvote; I just shook my head...)

I came in at a different angle.  @ArturoMagidin  Honestly it didn't even occur to me that it was $S_3$ until a moment passed.

You are still underdescribing it. You need to specify that the action is nontrivial. And since you chastised another for not thinking this is a beginner, you really think that they are so familiar with semidirect products (not one of the first constructions beginners encounter)?

C'mon @Arturo,  if I write just the semi-direct product of course I'm not referring to the trivial one.   However your point may stand in as much as the semi-direct product probably comes a little later in the development.

I know that. The putative beginner you were championing elsewhere... probably not so much. And there are situations where you can pick a non trivial action and still get a direct product (not with the given hypotheses, granted; but take any nonabelian group acting on itself by conjugation and take $G\rtimes G$).

Really. Interesting example!  @arturo

I think I understand your point, although I'm not entirely sure about the concept of Z3Z2. My approach is to collect all the elements in S3 with order 3 (since the order of Z3 is 3) along with the identity. Let N be the set {identity, (1 2 3), (2 1 3)}.
Since the order of (1 2 3) is 3 and (1 2 3)(1 2 3) = (2 1 3), N is a cyclic subgroup. The factor group S3/N consists of the elements {(1 2)N, N}, which is also cyclic because the order of (1 2)N is 2.
Thus, this provides a counterexample because S3 itself is not cyclic. Thanks for your help!

You're welcome,  and of course an element of order $n$ will always generate a  cyclic subgroup of the same order.
